# Regular Expression for deleting emoticons in R

Tags: r, regex

I trying to clean some text from twitter with R, I already cleaned par of it but I have some issues with some content for example

https://twitter.com/nayibbukele/status/1177696817565306881?lang=en

"A Layla le encantó New York  Pero siempre le gusta regresar a casa  "

StackOverflow doesn't render it here, but ther are unicode characters `<U+2764>` and `<U+FE0F>` embedded in the tweet.

I would like to delete all the text that contains these: `<U+0001F303>`, `<U+2764>`, `<U+FE0F>`
My code is

```
Dataset$text=gsub(" ?(f|ht)(tp)(s?)(://)(.*)[.|/](.*)", "", Dataset$text) 
Dataset$text=gsub("(f|ht)(tp)(s?)(*)", "", Dataset$text) 
# Eliminamos las entidades de retweet
Dataset$text = gsub("(RT|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)", "", Dataset$text)
#Removemos el @
Dataset$text = gsub("@\\w+", "", Dataset$text)
#Removemos todos los simbolos no numericos o que no esten en el idioma ingles/español
Dataset$text=gsub("[^0-9A-Za-záéíóúñÁÉÍÓÚÑ///' ]", "", Dataset$text) 
#Eliminamos los hashtags 
Dataset$text=gsub(" #\\S*","",Dataset$text) 
#Convertimos a lowercase
#Convert all text to lower case            
Dataset$text<- tolower(Dataset$text)
```

Comment: I suppose you want to only keep ASCII, right? Try `gsub("[^[:ascii:]]+", "", Dataset$text, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Are you calling "ó" an emoticon here? That doesn't seem like the right term. Do you just mean any non-ascii character? Do you want to delete them or replace them with a "close" ascii substitution? The code you posted seems to be doing a lot more than you ask which is confusing. And only having one input string and no desired output makes it difficult to guess exactly what you are trying to do. What OS are you using and what encoding do the strings involved use?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems that when i posted my question it has some "edit" that was not saved. What I want to delete is this kind of information <U+0001F303> when you visit the original post it has emoticons instead of unicode characters

Comment: So does  `gsub("[^[:ascii:]]+", "", Dataset$text, perl=TRUE)` help?

Comment: I tried with that line but it did not work so I created this regex and it got the job done Dataset$text=gsub("<U\\+?[0-9a-fA-F]+>", " ", Dataset$text) it deleted the <U+0001F303>, <U+2764>, <U+FE0F>. The results are: A Layla le encantó New York Pero siempre le gusta regresar a casa. Thanks for your help

Comment: The link provided didn't work for me , but the problem was solved with the regex I wrote. Thanks for all your help